# How to generate html with alpine.js extensions via xslt

Tags: xslt, saxon, alpine.js

I try to generate a single page application based on alpine.js.
The HTML should be generate form XML descriptions via XSLT.

Example for required output.

```
<div @notify="alert('Hello World!')">
    <button @click="$dispatch('notify')">
        Notify
    </button>
</div>
```

My try to generate this via xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"  indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="@notify">
            <xsl:text>alert('Hello World!')</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <button>
            <xsl:attribute name="@click">
                <xsl:text>$dispatch('notify')</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
             Notify
         </button>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Imput XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test/>
```

Result:

`Error in xsl:attribute/@name on line 8 column 39 of alpina.xsl: XTDE0850  Attribute name {@notify} is not a valid QName`

Comment: I don't think XML tools will be very helpful achieving that kind of output, you could try to find some "exotic" Unicode character allowed to start a name you don't expect elsewhere and later string replace it with `@`. But that is rather brittle. Can be done all from within a single XSLT 3 stylesheet, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know alpine.js, but we see similar problems with other "XML-like" or "HTML-like" formats.

XSLT works on the XDM data model, which defines concepts such as elements and attributes, and defines rules for the content, for example rules for element and attribute names (which don't allow them to start with "@"). If you want to generate something like the output you have shown, you first need to define a representation of this content using the XDM data model. This might include a mapping from XDM attribute names to alpine attribute names (for example, you could use the XDM attribute name `__notify` to represent the alpine attribute name `@notify`).

Then (a) your stylesheet would generate an XDM attribute named `__notify`, and (b) you would need a custom serialization method that serialises `__notify` as `@notify`.

The Saxon serialization machinery is highly customizable. If you want to integrate this fully, you could register a `SerializerFactory` with the Saxon `Configuration`, that registers a user-defined serialization method, and uses a subclass of XmlEmitter or HtmlEmitter to customize the output. For example you could override the `writeAttribute` method so it outputs `__notify="xxxx"` as `@notify="xxxx"`.